# Solve the quartic $x^4-4x^3+7x^2-6x-40$

Tags: polynomials

> Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this quartic?
>   $$x^4-4x^3+7x^2-6x-40$$

I've tried to get it down to multiple factors but just can't figure it out.

Comment: if there are no integer roots, next you try $(x^2 + ax+b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ with integers

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x4-4x3%2B7x2-6x-40) gives $(-5 - 2 x + x^2) (8 - 2 x + x^2)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that I think of it, the original factors over the rationals (as two quadratics) if and only if we can factor the depressed quartic. Take $ x = t+1$ to get
$$ t^4 + t^2 - 42 $$
But this is just
$$ (t^2 + 7)(t^2-6)  $$
and you can plug back $t=x-1$

Comment: Wow - I had never seen that method! (Not that me having seen or not seen something is much of an indicator...)

Comment: +1. To fully understand your nice answer, can I ask you what is a depressed quartic? Thanks.

Comment: @Dunkelheit it means you take a translate to make the coefficient of the cubic term become zero. It was possible to do this with an integer because the original cubic coefficient was divisible by $4$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Converting_to_a_depressed_quartic